# geolocation not working in mobile's browser Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently developing a mobile web page integrated with google map, and I need to include a `my location` button on the google map. in JavaScript i having something like this

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()
```

It is working in desktop browser, prompt me whether allot website access my location. In mobile browser it doesn't prompt me allow or deny, just throwing error says "User denied Geolocation".

Does anyone has come across this?

Comment: Are you using an iPhone?

Comment: Have you implemented Prompting for permission: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API#Prompting_for_permission

Comment: @Jerome Yes iPhone

Comment: @Justinas i have tried on Safari, chrome is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you'll have to allow location sharing on an iPhone.

Go to `Settings > General`, then go to `Reset > Reset Location & Privacy`.

If you intend this to be used by other users you'll have to [prompt for permission](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API#Prompting_for_permission) like Justinas stated.

Comment: Yes, after reset it prompt, before that i go through all the settings, every column seems correct to me. Thanks mate

Comment: No Problem, Happy to help :-)